# Addin plugin custom post type to members plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, members

I am using the Wp-Leads plugin and Members plugin and I want to create a new user with the role leads-admin. When I go into the leads-admin role I added these capabilities:

```
edit_wp-leads
delete_published_wp-leads
delete_wp-leads
edit_published_wp-leads
```

But when I log in as a user with the role leads-admin and I try to view the leads I get this message:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?